# How can I disable StopForumSpam spam filter in BlogEngine.NET 2.0

Tags: content-management-system, blogs, blogengine.net, spam-prevention

I'm using BlogEngine.NET v2.0.0.44 and I don't want any spam filters enabled as I plan to moderate all comments manually. I successfully disabled AkismetFilter and TypePadFilter by disabling their extensions, however I can not find a way to disable StopFormSpam filter. How can I disable this filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After little bit of debugging I found the root cause of this problem. StopForumSpam class seems to be a bit unfinished in this version of BlogEngine (2.0.0.44). You need Extension attribute StopForumSpam class like:

```
/// <summary>
/// StopForumSpam.com custom comment filter
/// </summary>
[Extension("StopForumSpam.com custom comment filter", "1.0", "<a href=\"http://dotnetblogengine.net\">BlogEngine.NET</a>")]
public class StopForumSpam : ICustomFilter
{
```

Also Initialize() method needs to look like:

```
/// <summary>
/// Enables or disables filter
/// </summary>
/// <returns>
/// True of false
/// </returns>
public bool Initialize()
{
    return ExtensionManager.ExtensionEnabled("StopForumSpam");
}
```

After this changes StopForumSpam extension will appear in the Extensions tab in admin panel where it can be enabled/disabled easily. It's strange that StopForumSpam class did not have this by default since both AksimetFilter and TypePadFilter have this and those classes have pretty much the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Delete App_Code/Extensions/StopForumSpam.cs from your blog and it will be gone.

Comment: Thanks for the answer rtur, your solution does work but only if the file is deleted before the first run of the BlogEngine. If you run once with StopForumSpam compiled, you can't get rid of it that easily later on. I've tried commenting out the entire class, deleting the file, clean/rebuild solution, restart web server but the filter keeps appearing in the 'Comments Rules & Filters'. Strange...